# Has anyone had any success using Dojo in Liferay 7 (Liferay DXP)

Tags: dojo, liferay

We are currently trying to include Dojo in our liferay 7 application and are running into major difficulties, as it seems the AMD loader is clashing with the AMD loader of Liferay, and its preventing Dojo's define and require from working properly.

If anyone as a solution to getting dojo into Liferay 7 I would appreciate any advice or tips you have for getting this to work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to help out with your question, we'll need more context: check out the guidelines on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include more steps on the code needed to reproduce the problem, the system you're working on, and what you've tried so far (including links to related questions). We'd like to help, but need you to help make this clearer!

Answer (score 0):

When using dojo application together with Liferay I could suggest you:

- Keep dojo loader requiring only AMD modules from dojo and not Liferay, so use dojo only for dojo and Liferay only for Liferay.
- Same when building the application, you need to have two separate build processes, dojo uses it own tools called [dojo/util](https://github.com/dojo/util) and you won't be able to easily build a dojo app using another builder.